# Adding a label_suffix to ModelForm

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

How do I change the `label_suffix` on a `ModelForm`?

I want the model form to remove ":" from all labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the form is instantiated, you can pass `label_suffix` into it as follows:

```
list_form = ListForm(label_suffix="")
```