# Setting label_suffix for a Django model formset

Tags: python, django

I have a Product model that I use to create ProductFormSet. How do I specify the label_suffix to be something other than the default colon? I want it to be blank. Solutions I've seen only seem to apply when initiating a form - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973954/adding-a-label-suffix-to-modelform).

```
ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product, exclude=('abc',))    
products = Product.objects.order_by('product_name')
pformset = ProductFormSet(queryset=products)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django 1.9+, you can use the [`form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) option.

```
ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product, exclude=('abc',))    
products = Product.objects.order_by('product_name')
pformset = ProductFormSet(queryset=products, form_kwargs={'label_suffix': ''})
```

In earlier Django versions, you could define a ProductForm class that sets the `label_suffix` to blank in the `__init__` method, and then pass that form class to `modelformset_factory`.

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label_suffix = ''

ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product, form=ProductForm, exclude=('abc',))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create custom tag:

```py
@register.filter("set_label_suffix")
def set_label_suffix(field, suffix=''):
    field.field.label_suffix = suffix
    return field
```

And then use in the template (also using `widget_tweaks` in this example):

```
{% for field in channel_change_form %}
   <div class="form-group">
       {{ field.errors }}
       {{ field|add_label_class:"col-form-label"}}
       {{ field|set_label_suffix|add_class:"form-control" }}
   </div>
...
```